# Equation of one of the two lines whose angle bisector is given.

Tags: coordinate-systems, reflection

A ray of light falling along the line $ lx+my+n=0 $ strikes a plane mirror at point $P$. Find the equation of reflected ray if $px+qy+r=0$ is the equation of normal to the plane at point $P$.

Comment: what difficulties are you having?

Comment: @DavidP There are two different equations possible as an answer to this equation

Comment: There is only one. The light reflects at the same angle it hits the surface. The second possibility you are getting may be assuming the light passes through the line

Comment: The equation of the reflected ray will be of the form $L_1+\lambda L_2$.In order to determine $\lambda$, I'm trying to equate the angle between this newly formed line and $L_2$ with the angle between $L_1$ and $L_2$ hence ending up with two different values of $\lambda$.How to ensure the uniqueness of $\lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's normalize things so that $l^2 + m^2 =1$ and $p^2 + q^2 = 1$. Then $\mathbf{L} = (-m,l)$ is a unit vector parallel to the incoming ray, and $\mathbf{N}=(p,q)$ is a unit vector perpendicular to the mirror. The incoming ray is along the line $(\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{P}) \times \mathbf{L} = 0$, and the mirror plane has equation $(\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{P}) \cdot \mathbf{N} = 0$. Let's use $\mathbf{M}$ to denote a unit vector parallel to the the out-going ray. Draw a little picture to convince yourself that $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{L} + 2[(\mathbf{L} \cdot \mathbf{N})\mathbf{N} - \mathbf{L} ]$ or $\mathbf{M} = 2(\mathbf{L} \cdot \mathbf{N})\mathbf{N} - \mathbf{L}$. 
Writing out all the coordinates:
$$
\mathbf{M} = (2lpq - 2mp^2 + m, 2lq^2 -2mpq -l)
$$
Now you have $\mathbf{M}$, you're done, because the out-going ray has equation $(\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{P}) \times \mathbf{M} = 0$.